# Hg clone only public commits

Tags: mercurial

We have a big Hg repo, hosted in a remote location. Performing an `hg clone` from this master repo takes about an hour. What we generally do to speed things up is to `hg serve` a local repo of a colleague, `hg clone http://colleague-machine`, and then change de `default` path in `.hg/hgrc` to the address of the master repo.

This is all well and good, but this workaround has one drawback: because we are cloning the repo of a developer, some draft commits can be cloned along with the public ones. Moreover, these commits become public in the cloned repo, making them indistinguishable from the others.

One possibility I found is to [make the developer's repo non publishing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#What_is_a_.22publishing_repository.22.3F), in order to preserve the phases of the commits and to remove them later on. Another possibility is to create a bundle containing only the public commits, instead of cloning directly.

These methods are more complex to explain and to document. Is there an option for `hg clone` to clone only the public commits? I tried with `hg clone -r "public()"`, but clone does not take a revset, just a regular commit identifer. Alternatively, is there an option for `hg serve` to serve only the public commits?

Comment: You may want to look into generating clonebundles on your main hg server.

Comment: Possibly. But this bundle would still reside on the other side of the planet, whereas my colleague has a fully functional repo 2 meters away from me, on a super fast local network :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `hg clone -r <rev>` where `<rev>` is public. That will ensure that you won't get any draft commits, although you will miss any branches that aren't ancestors of `<rev>`.

I don't think there's a generic way to clone only public changes. It might be possible via a server-side extension or in-process hook though.

Comment: That's a good idea, that would get me the bulk of the public commits (the ones in the default branch). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Throw disk space at the problem: just keep a local mirror clone that you update regularly.

Cloning the "true master" is slow because it's far away over a slow link.  But updating the mirror is fast because, while the true master is far away over a slow link, little data needs to traverse it; and cloning the mirror is fast, and gets you the state of the true master as of the last time the mirror was updated.

As you mention, you can then just replace the `default` path (and maybe run a subsequent `hg pull` to pick up anything not-yet-mirrored, if needed).  Your new clone is then the same as it would have been, had you cloned from the far-away slow true master, except that it went fast.

---

Git has this kind of cloning built in, as what's called a *reference clone*.  You point your `git clone` process at two repositories: the true source, and the "close and fast" reference.  It gets hash IDs from the true source but then uses the close-and-fast reference's storage for its data.  You can then choose to continue to rely on the reference (default) or "dissociate" from the reference so that your clone is independent.  It needs this dissociate operation because it can do a somewhat dangerous path-name-based "link" (not really a link in the sense of hard links; more an in-Git analogue to symbolic links) to the original, and does so by default here.

I don't think Mercurial has anything equivalent "out of the box".  I imagine it should be relatively easy to write as an extension, though, if you are up for that sort of thing.  You wouldn't need `--dissociate` at all, it would be the default wherever hard links are not feasible.

Comment: I did not consider this solution. That's a very reasonable solution. In my case the cost of setting this up outweights the benefits, because we'd need it very rarely. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of `hg serve` option and `hg strip`.

On the existing repository:

```
hg serve --config phases.publish=False --port 0 --prefix repo-name
```

On the target machine:

```
hg clone <address printed by `hg serve`>
cd repo-name
hg strip -r "draft()"
```

The `phases.publish=False` config makes the repo non-publishing, and thus preserves the phase of the commits that are cloned. Now that the phases are kept on the target machine, it is easy to strip them off after the clone.